# Word 2007 cannot open old doc files anymore

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Since last week I am unable to open old doc files with Microsoft Word 2007.

Whenever I try that I first get a warning about converters being a security issue. (I can disable that in the registry).

After accepting (or disabling) this warning, however, I just get the following error message:

```
Unglütiger Datentyp

(Word 6.0/95 für Windows & Macintosh
```

which means in English:

```
Invalid document type

(Word 6.0/95 for Windows & Macintosh
```

I tried to goolge both the German and the translated error message but did not find anything related.

The files in question can be opened by other users for the windows terminal server without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Microsoft Office Diagnostics program:

1. Click the Office button.
2. Click the Word Options button.
3. Click Resources.
4. Click the Diagnose button.
5. Click Continue, and then click Run Diagnostics.

If Microsoft Office Diagnostics fails, do a [repair installation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924611).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i don't have the require reputation yet, to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the 12.0\word registry key for the user and the problem went away.

I was not able to do a repair installation because the user account is not allowed to execute setup programs.

Comment: "the user account is not allowed to execute setup programs" ... but allowed to edit the registry??? ^^